# JqueryMobile for iPad problem

Tags: ipad, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile web app  created in a jquerymobile. It looks fine on mobile devices. But on iPad the app does not take up the full screen size. However it does take up full width size..which is fine. How can I make the app to take up full height of iPad screen...???.

Comment: Please edit your question and add some code, what version of JQM. Without knowing what the issue is I would suggest <div class="content-secondary"> <div class="content-primary">